# Select branch to build in Jenkins

Tags: xcode, jenkins, continuous-integration

I have several branches in my project. Is it possible to make dynamic branch selection in Jenkins's job?
The idea is that Jenkins will get list of current branches and display them as possible choice parameter. Is there any way to do that? Thanks

Comment: Which version control tool are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do that using [Extended Choice Parameter](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Extended+Choice+Parameter+plugin) plugin. Once you have installed the plugin, go to your job's configuration page. Now follow the steps mentioned below:

1. Enable check box `This build is parameterized`.
2. In the dropdown menu, `Add Parameter`, select `Extended Choice Parameter`
3. Since you will be selecting only *one* branch for a build, leave the `Parameter Type` as `Single Select`
4. In section `Choose Source for Value`, click on radio button `Property File`. Specify the absolute (full) path to the file.
5. Just below `Property File`, you will see `Property Key`. Here you have to specify the key. The property file is in the form of key-value pairs.
   For ex., `key=value1,value2,...`

As you can see from the property file content shown below, i will be using `branch_name` as the key in `Property Key` box.

```
[tom@master ]# cat /data/branch_list
branch_name=master,mainline,branch_A,branch_B,branch_C,branch_N,
```

Refer snapshot below for better understanding of what i explained above:

[image]

Now if you already have the branch list with you, you can create the property file in the format specified above. However, since branch creation happens from time-to-time, you need to *dynamically* fetch the list from your version control tool. We use Git so i can help you with that, if need be. If you use anything else, you will have to search for the required command. To get the branch list *dynamically*, i have set-up a cron which keeps checking the Git repo and fetches the list of branch. It then populates the property file with the *up-to-date* branch list which is then *dynamically* loaded by Jenkins.

**Update:**

We use Gitolite and access branch names using `git ls-remote` command.

```
git ls-remote gitolite@git.server.com:repository_name
```

For example,

```
[tom@master ~]$ git ls-remote gitolite@git.server.com:repository_name
08a119f0aec5d4286708d2e16275fcd7d80d2c25        HEAD
a91ef29f1be5bfe373598f6bb20d772dcc65b8ca        refs/heads/dev-mob
d138356cf752a46fd8c626229809c9eaae63a719        refs/heads/dev-ssorel
e7d7e2c617c4a42b299b29c0119283813800f1bb        refs/heads/dev-omni
3193b36d678f1af2dcc3a291c6313f28ede97149        refs/heads/dev-pay
72fd9d8586708011c763cd7bc4f7bd2a3513a12f        refs/heads/dev-sell
39455fc2672039a7f325e9cafe3777ed563368ef        refs/heads/dev-apis
a22eb000ffa1ac0fbbf51b6bc8aea31b040567a3        refs/heads/dev-front
78a63105ec754d7ba758af97d542e749ceb9c533        refs/heads/dev-tpsp
82d99796690b6c562872ea68655c74ebc3f0abfb        refs/heads/mainline
fd82522f9999cedb11e245b515d480187c2e9cc6        refs/heads/master
```

To filter out branch names only and populate the same in a file in the form of key-value pair, you can use this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

git ls-remote gitolite@git.server.com:repository_name | grep -v HEAD | cut -d/ -f3 | sort > /data/branch_list_temp
tr '\n' ',' < /data/branch_list_temp | sed "s/^\(.*\)/branch_name=\1/" > /data/branch_list

rm /data/branch_list_temp
```

**P.S.**: Make sure that the property file is on Jenkins Master (in case of Master-Slave setup).

Comment: Wow, Thanks for quick and exhaustive answer! I'll try it soon. Also, I use GIT.

Comment: How do you fetching branch names(and only names)? I'm trying to use the following 'git branch -r | sed -e 's/origin\///g' -e 's/HEAD.*//g''. Then parsing results and pasting them into branch_list file. I think there might be better way.

Answer (score 9):

I've found groovy script for this. A bit modified it. You need to select 'groovy script' instead of 'Property file'

```
def gitURL = "ssh://jenkins@phabricator.com/project.git"
def command = "git ls-remote -h $gitURL"

def proc = command.execute()
proc.waitFor()         

if ( proc.exitValue() != 0 ) {
   println "Error, ${proc.err.text}"
   System.exit(-1)
}     

def branches = proc.in.text.readLines().collect {
    it.replaceAll(/[a-z0-9]*\trefs\/heads\//, '') 
}   
return branches.join(",")
```

Idea is the same. Only now your key is ${Branch} in the job. Works well. Huge thanks @Technext for idea.

Comment: You're welcome! :) Thanks for posting the script! Will help others. :)