# Save values in parameterized build

Tags: jenkins

I am using parameterized build in Jenkins? Is there a way when changing the values of parameters (String parameters for example) to save them for next build instead of using the default?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Extended choise parameter plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Extended+Choice+Parameter+plugin) and set default value source to file [as described in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25766576/4157479).

Comment: Thanks, but in this example the developer uses external file for default configuration. This is not exactly what I wish to do.

Comment: May be [Rebuild plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Rebuild+Plugin) help you?