# jenkins parameterized build with nexus artifacts

Tags: plugins, deployment, jenkins, release, nexus

i am working on Jenkins to create a continuous integration. i want to create a job with parameters which will have a drop down list of artifacts that are stored in nexus and a drop down list of environment that we want those artifacts to be deployed to (web sphere). i am new to Jenkins and would like to get any help that will help me start the job.

Answer (score 2):

You will need [Extended Choice Parameter](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Extended+Choice+Parameter+plugin) plugin to achieve your goal.
You will have to store the list of artifacts fetched from Nexus in a file. Same goes for the list of environments. These files will then be picked up by the above plugin using the method described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25640028/select-branch-to-build-in-jenkins/25642499#25642499) link. `Property File` option is what you need to use in the given plugin.

Comment: @arjunD.: I'm glad it did. :) If it answered your query, please mark it as Answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use **Dynamic choice parameter**,

Then write a groovy script that will take the meatdata out from Nexus,

For me it's working just great.

```
import groovy.xml.*;
import groovy.util.*;

myUrl = "http://NexusServer.fo.net:8081/nexus/service/local/repositories/repo-name/content/groupID/maven-metadata.xml"


def data = new URL(myUrl).getText()

def dataObj = new XmlParser().parseText(data)
def versions=[]
for (v in dataObj.versioning[0].versions[0].version){
          versions.add(v.value()[0])
}
versions.sort(false).reverse()
```

This is how it looks at the end:

[image]

Comment: Distribution of This Plugin Has Been Suspended - Arbitrary code execution vulnerability