# How to get the branch version of svn as parameter choice in Jenkins

Tags: svn, jenkins, build, jenkins-plugins

I am running a maven project which require the branch version as parameter in Jenkins. Say /v88 which is same as the svn branch version. So say the current repository is http://xyz/svn/a-api/branches/Sprint88/tests. 
Is there any plugin for jenkins which automatically gets this version from the repository path? So when ever a new build is triggered it should automatically get the version from that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Extended Choice Parameter plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Extended+Choice+Parameter+plugin) with a Groovy script.

Here is an example for Git:
[Select branch to build in Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25640028/select-branch-to-build-in-jenkins)

Please have a look to the latest answer and adapt the Groovy script to SVN.

You can list all the branches with this SVN command:

```
svn ls -v http://your.svn.server/path/branches
```